# Android style inheritance not working

Tags: android, inheritance, styles

styles.xml

```
    <style name="Red" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium.Inverse">
        <item name="android:textColor">#f00</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Red.LARGE">
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    </style>
```

**When i use this;**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:text="@string/save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/save_marginTop"
    android:gravity="center"
    style="@style/Red.LARGE"/>
```

**This button attribute only Large and doest painting to Red. Why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Red.LARGE style needs to use the parent attribute.  Red.LARGE will inherit Red if it is changed to:

```
<style name="Red.LARGE" parent="Red">
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It is not recommended to mix `parent` attribute and dot notation. Anyway, `parent` always overrides dot notation.